# Is the microsoft C compiler (cl.exe) a compiler driver or a compiler?

Tags: compiler

`gcc`and `clang` are both known to be compiler drivers. As such, the `gcc` executable does not compile anything itself. Rather, it calls the compiler (`cc1`), assembler (`as`) and linker (`ld`) with the right flags as needed.

Is this setup true also for the Microsoft C compiler, `cl.exe`? Is there actually some other executable that does the compilation? I assume that at least the assembling and linking are done by separate executables, since I know that `ml.exe` (known as MASM) and `link.exe` exist as separate executables, so `cl.exe` probably calls them.

Comment: `clang` process simply calls `clang`. It does not need to be a separate binary, but there is a reason to run phases in separate processes, for a better error recovery.

Comment: Why the downvotes?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So the size of cl.exe is 158 KB. What do you think?

The rest of the MSVC C++ compiler is in various DLLs. The C/C++ compiler driver is officially cl.exe, but many of the driver functions are provided by MsBuild. Other executables include link.exe, lib.exe, ml.exe and bscmake.exe. You can't translate the archictecture or terminology blindly from one product set to another that is completely different.

However, if all you want to do is compile from the command line, cl.exe is the place to go. Details can be found here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7865432/command-line-compile-using-cl-exe.

Comment: MsBuild is not "the driver". It's an optional build system, like `make`.

Comment: @AndrewMedico: You've got a point. See edit.

Comment: The front-end C compiler is `c1.dll`, the front-end C++ compiler is `c1xx.dll`, and `c2.dll` is the back-end optimizing code-generator. The edit you made did not fix the answer. MSBuild has nothing to do with the compiler. It is just a way of *invoking* the compiler. Link.exe is the linker, lib.exe is a helper app that creates/manages libraries, ml.exe is MASM (the assembler)... None of these have anything to do with the compiler, either!

Comment: Moreover `lib.exe` is a shallow wrapper that effectively calls `link.exe /lib` ... similarly `dumpbin.exe` and `editbin.exe`. So even in that case the functionality only exists in one place (`link.exe`). Nothing to do with the compiler isn't entirely correct, though. But for all practical purposes it's the correct way of looking at things, I agree.